# how can i know which variable caused vue js re-rendering

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, vuejs3

I am using chrome-devtools to see the performance of my vue js application. The application contains many components.

I am seeing a wave  of updateComponent calls for all application componenets as you can see in the photo below.

I see compoent re-rendering even they do not have an html template.

How can i know which variable that caused vue js component re-rendering ?

[image]

Comment: There is no way to know which variable caused component re-rendering by the performance tab. You just can see which function is called and which file defines that function by clicking on the function name and see in the Summary tab